# RandomForest incorrect cutoff specified

Tags: random-forest

I am trying to change the default cutoff of randomForest in R. I'm using the form cutoff=c(0.7,0.3) and get an "Incorrect cutoff specified" error for any value used. What is the proper way to change the cutoff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's R RandomForest I know the correct format i this:

```
cutoff=c(k,1-k)
cutoff=c(0.7,0.3)
```

**EDIT**

The cutoff vector should have length equal to the number of classes. SO if you have 3 classes you must have

```
cutoff=c(a,b,c)
```

where a+b+c=1

Comment: I now get "argument 5 matches multiple formal arguments"

Comment: can you show the whole randomForest(...) that you are using?

Comment: RandomForest(x, y, mtry=2, ntree=500, c=cutoff(0.7,0.3)

Comment: Try using like this `RandomForest(x, y, mtry=2, ntree=500, cutoff=c(0.7,0.3)`

Comment: That was the original attempt that resulted in "Incorrect cutoff specified".

Comment: In the question, the dots are in the incorrect postion see: `cutoff=c(.07,.03)`
I asked you to try `cutoff=c(0.7,0.3)` Remembering also that the parameters must add to 1

Comment: Yes, sorry. That is only a typo in the question. I have 0.7,0.3 in randomForest.